# Axios setRequestHeader method with UTF-8

Tags: node.js, reactjs, utf-8, character-encoding, httprequest

I am trying to add some headers in my request. But header values may include some Turkish characters (like ğ, ş, ö etc.) and when I tried this, I got this error:

```
TypeError: Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': String contains non ISO-8859-1 code point.
    at setRequestHeader (xhr.js:132)
    at Object.forEach (utils.js:253)
    at dispatchXhrRequest (xhr.js:126)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at xhrAdapter (xhr.js:13)
    at dispatchRequest (dispatchRequest.js:52)
    at :3000/report/async http:/localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:4137
```

I guess axios supports ISO-8859-1 characters when add my custom headers to header list. Is it possible change axios' supported charset to UTF-8?

Comment: Have you solve it?

Comment: @chenop I solved it.   let headers = {"userId": user.id, "username":user.username, "relatedName": encodeURIComponent(values.username)};  Encode at React.  relatedName = URLDecoder.decode(request.getHeader("relatedName"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()); Decode at Java.

Answer (score 1):

let headers = {"userId": user.id, "username":user.username, "relatedName": **encodeURIComponent(values.username)**}; Encode at React. **relatedName = URLDecoder.decode(request.getHeader("relatedName"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());** Decode at Java.